# Error with Motoman SDA10F package

Tags: ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
When I try the instruction `roslaunch motoman_sda10f_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=true`, the next errors appear

```
[ INFO] [1448860557.614217751]: Loading robot model 'motoman_sda10f'...
[ERROR] [1448860558.119278078]: Group 'torso' is not a chain
[ERROR] [1448860558.119350084]: Kinematics solver of type 'kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin' could not be initialized for group 'torso'
[ERROR] [1448860558.119792175]: Kinematics solver could not be instantiated for joint group torso.
[ INFO] [1448860558.126523519]: Loading robot model 'motoman_sda10f'...
[ERROR] [1448860558.572781895]: Group 'arms' is not a chain
[ERROR] [1448860558.572861970]: Kinematics solver of type 'kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin' could not be initialized for group 'arms'
[ERROR] [1448860558.573263572]: Kinematics solver could not be instantiated for joint group arms.
[ INFO] [1448860558.578935053]: Loading robot model 'motoman_sda10f'...
[ERROR] [1448860559.023278249]: Group 'sda10f' is not a chain
[ERROR] [1448860559.023357702]: Kinematics solver of type 'kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin' could not be initialized for group 'sda10f'
[ERROR] [1448860559.023930325]: Kinematics solver could not be instantiated for joint group sda10f.
[ WARN] [1448860883.486564338]: Failed to call service /get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group? at /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-moveit-ros-planning-0.6.5-0trusty-20151112-0345/planning_scene_monitor/src/planning_scene_monitor.cpp:461
[ERROR] [1448860575.979981301]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: sda10f/sda10f_r1_controller/joint_trajectory_action
[ INFO] [1448860581.096676607]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Waiting for sda10f/sda10f_b1_controller/joint_trajectory_action to come up
[ INFO] [1448860586.096886543]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Waiting for sda10f/sda10f_b1_controller/joint_trajectory_action to come up
[ERROR] [1448860591.097130984]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: sda10f/sda10f_b1_controller/joint_trajectory_action
[ INFO] [1448860596.225098638]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Waiting for sda10f/sda10f_b2_controller/joint_trajectory_action to come up
[ INFO] [1448860601.225290651]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Waiting for sda10f/sda10f_b2_controller/joint_trajectory_action to come up
```

So, I can't plan trajectories.

How can I solve it?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221714/error-with-motoman-sda10f-package/) by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-11-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-30**:
I've cross-posted this to the ROS-I [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/swri-ros-pkg-dev/dhvpNOGO7RU/-EVR5UWRBwAJ). In the meantime: can you tell us how you installed the package, and on what OS and ROS version?

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2015-12-01**:
Thanks for your answer. I installed the package from source according with this link [motoman_indigo](http://answers.ros.org/question/191233/how-can-i-use-motoman-stack-with-ros-indigo/), on Ubuntu 10.04.1 (trusty) with ROS Indigo.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-01**:
Ok. Please report this issue at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/issues) at the `motoman` repository. You can just refer to your question on ROS answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simulation mode for the motoman package doesn't support dual arm configuration at this time.  If you simply want to plan in MoveIt, you can do this using `roslaunch motoman_sda10f_moveit_config demo.launch`.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2015-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2015-12-01**:
Thanks for your answer.

I had tried the instruction that you suggested, but it shows the errors about the robot isn't a chain. Additionally, in MoveIt I can plan just for the left robot.

And, isn't it possible to connect with the real robot?

Thank you

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2015-12-01**:
Something must have changed in the underlying MoveIt library (or maybe it never worked).  I will verify this tonight.  Connecting to the real robot is possible assuming the latest driver code (indigo) is loaded.  Connecting to a simulated robot is not supported.

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2015-12-01**:
I have verified the issue.  The MoveIt configuration appears correct.  I'm working to track to the cause of the issue.  Thanks for reporting this.

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2015-12-01**:
Thanks for your help.
I installed the driver one year ago, so I suppose it isn't the latest available. Could you tell me how to update it? and please let me know if you find out how to fix this problem, I am working with a robot like it. How could I try to track the cause?

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2015-12-01**:
It turns out to not be an issue.  The other planning groups can be selected under Motion Planning->Planning Request->Planning Group.  Only the arms have a valid IK solver.  Interactive markers won't appear for other groups.  Planning can be done on other groups using "random" positions.

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2015-12-02**:
Thank you so much for your help. The planning in MoveIt works well, I'll try to connect with the real robot then I tell you. Thanks again.

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2015-12-05**:
I got this:

```
 [ERROR] [1449332869.289388644]: Failed to parse position data from JointFeedbackMessage
    [ERROR] [1449332869.289693349]: Failed to convert SimpleMessage
```

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2015-12-05**:
[ERROR] [1449332869.299495332]: Message callback for message type: 17, not executed
[ERROR] [1449332869.320907873]: Failed to copy JointData.  Len (11) out of range (0 to 10)

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2015-12-07**:
Please start a new question to address this.